# counting time point in chrono library

Tags: c++, time, c++-chrono

I'm using chrono library for the first time so please be lenient C:. So I want to write a simple get time function that return just processor tics with chrono. But when i try to use `clock()` function to get the value from a time point initialized with `steady_clock::now()`, gcc says that `time_point` doesn't contain `count()` member.

```
/home/siery/Documents/Project/ChangeStateMachine/main.cpp|41|error: ‘struct std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, std::chrono::duration<long long int, std::ratio<1ll, 1000000000ll> > >’ has no member named ‘count’|
```

Here is the code:

```
float GetTime()
{
    float tic = 0.0;
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    tic = (float)start.count();

    return tic;
}
```

Thank you!

Edit:

`GetTime()` function should return current time to calculate delta time to frequently update objects in my program like:

```
fPastTime = fCurrentTime;
fCurrentTime = GetTime();

fDt = fCurrentTime - fPastTime;
if (fDt >= 0.15f)
    fDt = 0.15f;
Update(fDt);
```

Comment: So you want to get the ticks since epoch? Its a bit unclear to me. How can you return processor ticks from a single time point?

Comment: I just want to return ticks since i start this function and use them to count delta time. Yes.. i didnt explain that  :)

Comment: I think `count()` is a member of `duration` not `time_point`. Use `count()` when you take the *difference* between start and end times.

Comment: Would it be possible for `GetTime()` to return `std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point`?  This would provide significant type safety as opposed to returning `float` (which could mean absolutely anything).

Comment: It is possible but then i will need to convert this value to float outside of this function to get correct delta time. Thats just more work and one think i can forget of.

Comment: `GetTime()` at one point minus `GetTime()` at another point will result in a `std::chrono::duration`.  If you want, you can assign that result to a `std::chrono::duration<float>`, and that will be a difference of seconds represented with a `float`.  You can extract the `float` from that difference `diff` with `diff.count()`.

Comment: Do i need to do all that? Cant i just get tics since now in chrono?

Comment: I have been attempting to communicate as widely as possible that use of `.count()` and `.time_since_epoch()` is as dangerous as a `reinterpret_cast`.  If you don't know what you're doing, these functions are likely to gift you with run time errors.  Yes, you can get tics since epoch from `steady_clock`.  And that result has absolutely no meaning whatsoever.  It is if somebody gave you a stopwatch and asked you to give them the time of day from it.

Comment: In your update what units does `0.15f` represent?  nanoseconds?  seconds? fortnights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommendation:

```
std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point
GetTime()
{
    return std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
}
```

If you want the result of the timing in terms of float-based seconds, do this:

```
using fsec = std::chrono::duration<float>;
auto t0 = GetTime();
some_function();
auto t1 = GetTime();
fsec delta = t1 - t0;
std::cout << delta.count() << "s\n";
```

- You are not responsible for any units conversions, therefore you will not introduce any bugs in this area.
- The code is simple.  Simple == low risk.
- There is really not a need for the `GetTime()` wrapper.

Edit:

```
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono;

using fsec = duration<float>;
using ftp = time_point<steady_clock, fsec>;

ftp
GetTime()
{
    return steady_clock::now();
}

int
main()
{
    auto fPastTime = GetTime();
    auto fCurrentTime = GetTime();

    auto fDt = fCurrentTime - fPastTime;
    if (fDt >= 0.15s)
        fDt = 0.15s;
    // ...
}
```

The `0.15s` requires C++14.  In C++11 that looks like:

```
    if (fDt >= fsec{0.15})
        fDt = fsec{0.15};
```

Comment: thats not really what this function spouse to do, as I say before, I just want to get current processor ticks to calculate delta time in main loop

Comment: Ok, i see, i thought someone is able to explain me why i cant just get current ticks and then compute them but I will need to move to some less heating focus forum. Any ways thank you Howard, that was helpful!

Answer (score 1):

As you've found, `time_point` doesn't have a `count` member.

You need to call `time_since_epoch` to get a duration, then you can call `count` on that:

```
float GetTime()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    return start.time_since_epoch().count();
}
```

I'm not sure a `float` is the best choice here though--I'd prefer something like `long long`, given a choice.

You'd normally just get (and store) a start time (as a `time_point`) and an end time (also as a `time_point`). Subtracting the two gives a `duration`, from which you can get a `count` (but you usually want to use a `duration_cast` to turn that into something more meaningful like nanoseconds before using/displaying it).

Comment: I need float to calculate dt. And i already know it works with time_since_epoch() but i want to get time since "now" :). I can easily get it by writing start.time_since_epoch() =- start.time_since_epoch().. but why this unnecessary calculation?

Comment: @siery: No, you don't (at least normally) need a float. Duration already typically uses a rational number as its representation (and the error message shows it does in your case). As I said, you usually want to get `now()` at the beginning of what you're timing, then again at the end. Subtract the two, and that gives a duration. Convert that to something meaningful, and get a count of nanoseconds, microseconds, etc.

Comment: maybe you're looking for `(std::chrono::stready_clock::now() - start).count()`